# Once I click a menu option the whole page scrolls with it? How Do I stop this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Once I click a menu option the whole page scrolls with it? How Do I stop this?

located on line 411 in jsfiddle

```
<style>@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300|Raleway:400,600,300|Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,300);
    @charset 'UTF-8';
    /* Base Styles */
    #cssmenu,
    #cssmenu ul,
    #cssmenu li,
    #cssmenu a {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0;
      list-style: none;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-decoration: none;
      line-height: 1;
      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;
      font-size: 15px;
      position: relative;



    }
    #cssmenu a {
      line-height: 1.3;
    }
    #cssmenu {
      width: 200px;

    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
      padding-right: 40px;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
      display: block;
      background: #000000;
      color: #9C9C9C;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
      text-transform: uppercase;

    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
      background: #000000;
      padding: 10px;
      display: block;
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.active {
      border-bottom: none;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
      color: #fff;
    }
    #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a span {
      background: #000000;
    }
    #cssmenu span.cnt {
      position: absolute;
      top: px;
      right: 15px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      background: none;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }
    /* Sub menu */
    #cssmenu ul ul {
      display: none;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li {
      border: 1px solid #2A2A2A;
      border-top: 0;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul a {
      padding: 10px;
      display: block;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: 200;
      font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
      color: gray;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li.odd {
      background: #2E2E2E;
    }
    #cssmenu ul ul li.even {
      background: #2E2E2E;
    }</style>

    <style>
        .class_slidshow2 {
       padding-left: 200px;
    }
    .rslides li {
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      padding-left: 200px;
      }



    <style>.slideshow {
        font-size: 30px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        color: #a81c11;
        display:inline;
        width: 80%; /* or dependent on what you like */
        float: left;

    } 

    .slideshow {
        float: right;
        display:inline;
        width: 20%; /* relative to width for introtekst */

    }</style>
```

I also several have other problems. How do I keep or "stick" the whole navmenu to the right when scrolling? In a more detailed question. I want my content to be on the right of the navmenu, there will be a lot of content so once the user scrolls they should still be able to see the navmenu without having to scroll back up, and it's for my personal appeal.

located on line 411 in jsfiddle

```
    <style>@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300|Raleway:400,600,300|Source+Sans+Pro:400,600,300);
@charset 'UTF-8';
/* Base Styles */
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;



}
#cssmenu a {
  line-height: 1.3;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;

}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding-right: 40px;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: block;
  background: #000000;
  color: #9C9C9C;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #393939;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
  background: #000000;
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {
  border-bottom: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #fff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a span {
  background: #000000;
}
#cssmenu span.cnt {
  position: absolute;
  top: px;
  right: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
/* Sub menu */
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  border: 1px solid #2A2A2A;
  border-top: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: gray;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.odd {
  background: #2E2E2E;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.even {
  background: #2E2E2E;
}</style>

<style>
    .class_slidshow2 {
   padding-left: 200px;
}
.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 200px;
  }



<style>.slideshow {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #a81c11;
    display:inline;
    width: 80%; /* or dependent on what you like */
    float: left;

} 

.slideshow {
    float: right;
    display:inline;
    width: 20%; /* relative to width for introtekst */

}</style>
```

I also noticed that on all browsers the background moves when the user scrolls. This causes the whole page to look disorientated. I did try to , position: fix; , but that had no effect.

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8GzLv/

Paste the whole markup in: http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/html/testbed.html  ,so you can see what I am talking about. Or zoom out of Jsfiddle within the browser.

This is the styling for the background: located on line 334 in Jsfiddle

```
<style>#headerWrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black; /* Omit to see body content scroll behind radius.  */
}
#headerBorder{
    border: black; 
    border-radius: 35px; 
    -moz-border-radius: 35px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 35px; 
    overflow:hidden;
}
#headerContent {
    background-image:url("http://www.fimfiction-static.net/images/story_images/92970_r.png?1364253348");
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
    opacity: 1;
}</style>
```

And how do I get the content to the top of the screen, and right next to the navmenu

Comment: You really need to clean up your code first. You have nested <style> tags which is probably affecting why styles are being processed by the  browser.

Comment: Ah yeah I know, I was waiting till after I was done with the whole project to clean it.

Comment: You should also ask 1 question, not several. Some people may be able to answer 1 or 2 of your questions but not all of them and therefore not answer at all.

Comment: Understood. I just thought it would make it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to float your menu to the left if you want the content to appear at the top of the screen, as well as give your slideshows widths that are less than 1100px. Next, if you want the nav-bar to stop affecting your content, the content will have to be in its own div. I would float that div to the right instead of the individual slideshow divs. Lastly, to get the navbar to scroll with you, you need to give it a position of fixed, or use some javascript. Anyways, it seems that you'll want to use a column layout, so I suggest looking that up.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8GzLv/1/

I tried not to change your code too much, so the css is in one of your style tags. But like I mentioned above, there is now a div around your slideshows with the class of content, and a div around your menu with the class of menu-placeholder.

But the important css parts to look at are:

```
.content {
    width:800px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.menu-placeholder {
    float:left;
    clear:left;
    min-height:250px;
    width:200px;

}
#cssmenu {
    position:fixed;
    top:150px;
}
```